# Flutter - Get array from Firestore with FutureBuilder (using query)

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm confusing myself terribly here...what is the correct syntax for listing an array from Firestore with FutureBuilder if I need to perform a document (where) query?

**Firestore Database Structure:**

```
 - [companies]
   - [doc]

 - [gallery]
   - [doc]
    - [reference] <- (ie, companies/doc)
    - [gallery_images] // List these, but show only images that match where() query
```

Here is my current code:

```
Future<List<dynamic>> getGallery() async {
  var firestore = Firestore.instance;

  DocumentReference docRef = firestore.collection('companies').document(widget.docID);

  var ref = firestore.collection('galleries').where('companyRef', isEqualTo: docRef).getDocuments();

  return ref.get().then((datasnapshot) {
        if (datasnapshot.exists) {
        List<dynamic> imageArray = datasnapshot.data['gallery_images'].toList();
          return imageArray;
        } else {
          print("Please just work...");
        }
      },
    );
  }
```

```
FutureBuilder(
  future: getGallery(),
  builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<List<dynamic>> snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
      return Center(
         child: Text("Loading..."),
        );
       } else {
    return GridView.builder(
    gridDelegate: new SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 2),
    itemCount: *length*,
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
       return ViewGalleryItemThumbnail(
         viewGalleryItem: snapshot.data[index],
         ....
```

Would really appreciate if someone can show me where I'm going wrong!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not exactly clear what your Cloud Firestore schema looks like, but this looks more likely to return you the correct list of dynamics. (Note that by adding a generic to the map you could return a list of specifically what you want - e.g. `.map<SomeRealType>((snap) => snap.data['gallery_images'])`.)

When you're stuck with `FutureBuilder` it's sometimes useful to revert temporarily to a stateful widget. Override `initState`, and call a slightly modified `getGallery` which doesn't return a value at the end, but assigns it to a member variable inside `setState`. Plenty of opportunity for print statements that way. Additionally, try to convert any `.then`s in an async function into a linear series of `await`s. It makes it easier to read (and your debug prints come out in a linear sensible order).

```
  Future<List<dynamic>> getGallery() async {
    var firestore = Firestore.instance;

    var docRef = firestore.collection('companies').document(widget.docID);

    var querySnap = await firestore
        .collection('galleries')
        .where('companyRef', isEqualTo: docRef)
        .getDocuments();

    return querySnap.documents
        .map((snap) => snap.data['gallery_images'])
        .toList();
  }
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your explanation and example, much appreciated! I'm almost there - it seems to be returning an array of images, though how do I insert that into a FutureBuilder? If I have eight images in gallery_images, then use getGallery() in a FutureBuilder, print(snapshot.data.length) only returns 1 (I assume it's counting the array a a whole, not counting the individual images). If I manually specify 1 as the itemcount in a GridView.builder, then I can return the first image in the array with "snapshot.data[index][0]". Can you see where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that there are actually 8 images returned by the query? What do `print(snapshot.data.runtimeType);` and/or `print(snapshot.data);` produce?

Comment: Ok, this is weird - print(snapshot.data) returns 4 full URLs and 1 partial URL (https://pastebin.com/HNbLhy9g) ?? RuntimeType returns List<dynamc>

Comment: Shortened the URLs with asterisks. The last URL is the full one as it appears. Also noticed the two opening square brackets and no closing brackets. Very strange?

Comment: The truncation is just the console running out of room. So, we have an array that contains another array (of strings). So, in firestore, I bet `gallery_images` is defined as an array. Yes, that makes sense: your query returns a list of documents (maybe just one - yes, that's why you see length 1) and that contains an array of images. So, in your builder use `snapshot.data[0][index]` - taking the zeroth document and indexing through its images.

Comment: You are the absolute best! It works perfectly now :D Thanks so much for all your help and explanations - it is all so much clearer now. Really appreciate it a lot!