# Flutter : problem writing the document in firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I made a list of documents in firestore in firebase with image , title , price and number(index of doc) property when I write values in property in firestore they didint update all in application some of them are miss as NULL in consell run .

to fix it :
to fix the issue is to make update in value again so will fix but who will update it so many time.

The full code is :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
  home: Home(),

));





class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}


class _HomeState extends State<Home> {


  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    GetDatafromFirebase();
  }

  GetDatafromFirebase() {
    Firestore.instance
        .collection('DesginStore')
        .document('Logo')
        .collection('sub')
    .orderBy('number',descending: false)
        .snapshots()
        .listen((data) =>
        data.documents.forEach((doc) => print("Title is :${doc["title"]}  And for order number is ${doc["number"]}")));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Text('Fortesting'),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

the result in app is(video) :
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FCKI3W5XTmVgTbtXKpYLHMrzAFya7AgQ/view?usp=sharing

[image: image from firestore]

Comment: It'll be helpful to show how you're using the data from Firebase in your `build` method

Comment: @YaobinThen Can you sir explain more ?

Comment: @KhalifaAlkhatre My first thought is that **DesginStore** is spelt incorrectly in `.collection('DesginStore')`. If you managed to spell it correctly in Firestore, it should say **DesignStore** in your code. Please check your code for spelling mistakes in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest familiarizing with some of the architectures used by other developers.

https://codewithandrea.com/videos/2020-02-10-starter-architecture-flutter-firebase/

or taking a look at this

[Flutter - Get array from Firestore with FutureBuilder (using query)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56571059/flutter-get-array-from-firestore-with-futurebuilder-using-query)

Only difference would be that you need to call setState on listening to changed data.

Comment: Thank you sir so much for information its helpfull and worked for me but this not going to solve the issue  above , I think this issue from firebase server.